# IndexOf function in cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have to search some string in node property. like

```
START user=node(*)
WHERE user.FirstName =~ '(?i).*run.*' 
RETURN indexof(user.FirstName, 'run');
```

Can I use like this, or any other function exist to get containing words.

thanks

Comment: Right now there are only these string functions: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-functions-string.html You'll have to do it in client code for now.

Comment: yes @MichaelHunger, that I read before. but is there any way to do this with cypher? I have create issue on github earlier.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a trivial addition to Cypher based on the string functions I added here: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/commit/7ad5446360ccbac607b137ccb4f8978dc2e455c6. In fact, I might go ahead and add it tonight if I get a chance. I'll update here if I get to it. The only reason it is slightly more complicated than cut/paste is the new parser requires a few more updates.

Comment: Did you ever do this?

Comment: nope, I guess I was busy that night and promptly forgot.